# Drawing a Bloch sphere with planes along z-axis in TikZ/PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I would like to draw a Bloch sphere that has planes at a certain z value (that can be specified). For example something like this:

[image]

I don't need the shading to be similar, only for the plane to be clear in a 3D Blosh sphere. I currently have the following output:

[image: Bloch sphere]

which has been generated from the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,11pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,angles} 
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=round, >=Triangle]
\clip(-2.1,-2.1) rectangle (2.38,2.58);

\draw[ball color=gray!20!white, fill opacity=0.6] (0,0) circle (2cm);   
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt] (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 0.9cm);   \draw (0,0)-- (0.70,1.07);


\draw[-to,line width=0.7pt]   (0,0) -- +(0,2);   \draw[-to,line width=0.7pt]   (0,0) -- +(-0.83,-0.81);   \draw[-to,line width=0.7pt]  (0,0) -- +(2,0);    


\draw [-Latex, <-, >=stealth', shift={(0,0)}, black, fill opacity=1] (56.7:0.4) arc (56.7:90.:0.4);   
\begin{scope}[rotate around x=10, y=10, xshift=1, yshift=-4.6]   
\draw [-Latex, ->, >=stealth', shift={(0,0)}, black, fill opacity=1] (-135.7:0.4) arc (-135.7:-33.2:0.4);   
\end{scope}

\draw [dotted] (0.7,1)-- (0.7,-0.46);   
\draw [dotted] (0,0)-- (0.7,-0.46); 
\draw [fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);   
\draw [fill] (0.7,1.07) circle (0.5pt); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This draws the planes at some latitudes, if needed this can be changed to accepting z values as input. The view angle theta can be changed at will.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{00}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R=2;}]
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,samples=101]
  \fill[blue,opacity=0.8] plot[domain=0:360,variable=\t,smooth cycle] 
      (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude=-10,longitude=\t);
  \fill[red,opacity=0.8] plot[domain=0:360,variable=\t,smooth cycle] 
      (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude=30,longitude=\t);
 \end{scope}
 \shade[ball color=red,opacity=0.4] (0,0) circle[radius=R];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can also specify `z`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{00}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R=2;angle(\z)=asin(\z/R);}]
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,samples=101]
 \path[draw,fill=red] plot[domain=90:270,variable=\t,smooth] 
      (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude={angle(0.5)},longitude=\t)
      plot[domain=270:90,variable=\t,smooth] 
      (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude={angle(0.5)+3*cos(\t)},longitude=\t);   
  \path[draw,opacity=0.8,inner color=red!40,outer color=red!80] plot[domain=0:360,variable=\t,smooth cycle] 
      (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude={angle(0.5)},longitude=\t);
 \end{scope}
 \shade[ball color=red,opacity=0.4] (0,0) circle[radius=R];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={R=4;angle(\z)=asin(\z/R);myz=0.8;
        myphi=50;mytheta=60;rr=4;},
 >=stealth]
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,samples=101]
  \path[draw,fill=red] plot[domain=90-\tdplotmainphi:270-\tdplotmainphi,variable=\t,smooth] 
       (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude={angle(myz)},longitude=\t)
       plot[domain=270-\tdplotmainphi:90-\tdplotmainphi,variable=\t,smooth] 
       (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude={angle(myz)+3*cos(\t+\tdplotmainphi)},longitude=\t);   
   \path[draw,opacity=0.8,inner color=red!40,outer color=red!80] 
     plot[domain=0:360,variable=\t,smooth cycle] 
       (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude={angle(myz)},longitude=\t);
  \draw[->] (0,0,myz) -- ({R*cos(asin(myz/R))},0,myz);
  \draw[->] (0,0,myz) -- (0,{R*cos(asin(myz/R))},myz);
  \draw[->] (0,0,myz) -- (0,0,R);
  \draw (0,0,myz) -- (xyz spherical cs:radius=rr,
    latitude=mytheta,longitude=myphi) coordinate(P) node[circle,fill,inner
    sep=1pt]{};
  \draw[dotted] (P) -- 
    ({rr*sin(myphi)*cos(mytheta)},{rr*cos(myphi)*cos(mytheta)},{myz})
    -- (0,0,myz);
  \draw[->] plot[domain=90:{atan((rr*sin(mytheta)-myz)/(rr*cos(mytheta)))},
    variable=\t,smooth] ([yshift=myz*1cm]xyz spherical cs:radius=1,latitude={\t},longitude=myphi);
  \draw[->] plot[domain=90:myphi,
    variable=\t,smooth] ({0.6*sin(\t)},{0.6*cos(\t)},myz);
 \end{scope}
 \shade[ball color=red,opacity=0.4] (0,0) circle[radius=R];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={R=4;angle(\z)=asin(\z/R);myz=0.8;
        myphi=50;mytheta=60;rr=4;a=myz/(rr*sin(mytheta));},
 >=stealth]
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,samples=101]
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- ({R*cos(asin(myz/R))},0,0);
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,{R*cos(asin(myz/R))},0);
  \draw[-] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,myz);
  \draw (0,0,0) -- (xyz spherical cs:radius=rr*a,
    latitude=mytheta,longitude=myphi) coordinate(P');
  \path[draw,fill=red] plot[domain=90-\tdplotmainphi:270-\tdplotmainphi,variable=\t,smooth] 
       (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude={angle(myz)},longitude=\t)
       plot[domain=270-\tdplotmainphi:90-\tdplotmainphi,variable=\t,smooth] 
       (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude={angle(myz)+3*cos(\t+\tdplotmainphi)},longitude=\t);   
  \path[draw,opacity=0.8,inner color=red!40,outer color=red!80] 
     plot[domain=0:360,variable=\t,smooth cycle] 
       (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,latitude={angle(myz)},longitude=\t);
  \draw[->] (0,0,myz) -- (0,0,R);
  \draw (P') -- (xyz spherical cs:radius=rr,
    latitude=mytheta,longitude=myphi) coordinate(P) node[circle,fill,inner
    sep=1pt]{};
 \end{scope}
 \shade[ball color=red,opacity=0.4] (0,0) circle[radius=R];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately I do not know in which plane the x and y axis should lie in.

Please note that there is also the `blochsphere` package, which specializes on Bloch spheres.

Comment: The latter is what am looking for. Is it possible to add the labels as shown in my attempt in the post (i.e. the axes, z=0 plane, and vector to a point on the chosen plane)?

Comment: @Sid It is possible.

Comment: So the second figure what what I was looking for, with the axes drawn from the origin of the sphere. Is the coordinate `P'` for the point? I want that to always be in the plane at height z. Also the axes lines `->` should be of length R, that lie on the equator.